# Como alinhar o título das colunas de uma JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Eu tenho uma tabela(abstract table model) e gostaria de centralizar os títulos das colunas.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centralizado = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();        
centralizado.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centralizado);
```

O que esta errado? Não é possível fazer apenas desta maneira?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código apresentado só irá definir a renderização da células da coluna, o cabeçalho é renderizado a parte.

Para centralizar o título das colunas você deve passar o renderer para o [**`JTableHeader`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html) da tabela, que é o responsável pela renderização do cabeçalho:

```
JTableHeader header =  jTable1.getTableHeader();
DefaultTableCellRenderer centralizado = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) header.getDefaultRenderer();
centralizado.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Ou em uma chamada de uma linha:

```
((DefaultTableCellRenderer) jTable1.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Comment: @GustavoSantos essa solução resolveu o problema?

Comment: resolveu perfeitamente !